# The output is being different when in the end we are doing the same operations in C++

Tags: c++

For some reason when doing few calculations, I am getting the output that is not what was expected.

Here we calculate b from a=5, why are the outputs of b being different and why is it 28 when it should be 26 (12+14) but is it being 26 when done separately.
Even after removing the brackets when calculating in one line, it gives the same output (28)

The code for the calculations that I did-

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    a = 5;
    b = 2 * ++a;   //first part of the calculation
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b<<std::endl;  
    b =b+2 * ++a;  //second part of the calculation
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout<<b<<std::endl; //It is coming as 26 when done separately

    //RESTARTING THE OPERATION FROM SAME VALUES TO FIND B IN ONE LINE

    a = 5;
    std::cout << 2 * ++a << std::endl;
    std::cout << 2 * ++a << std::endl;
    a = 5;
    b = (2 * ++a) + (2 * ++a); //b being calculated in one line
    std::cout << a << std::endl;//But 28 when done in one line
    std::cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(2 * ++a) + (2 * ++a);`  is undefined behaviour.

Comment: *it should be 26*. This is incorrect, your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: `a + ++a` is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec), let alone `(2 * ++a) + (2 * ++a)`.

Comment: Why bother? Just do `b = 4 * a + 6;` if that is the result you want.

Comment: @BoP My roommates are learning C++, they asked me why it was happening, and I wasn't able to understand which is why I posted it here, otherwise I would have also used a general way to calculate it too